How to get real-time customer information for PayPal payments using API or webhooks in Python?
I have a scenario where customers don't use our online shop to pay via PayPal. Instead, we send them an offer with instructions to pay to a specific bank account or via PayPal to a provided email address.
When a customer chooses to pay via PayPal, I receive an email notification containing the customer's name, email, reference, and the payment amount. This information would be perfect for my needs.
However, I am also using an ERP system (Odoo 16) and want to get this customer information into the system in real-time as soon as the payment is made. I previously used a built-in module for this purpose, but it was not real-time and was unstable.
My question is: Is it possible to retrieve the customer's name, email, amount paid, and note/reference in real-time using the PayPal API or webhooks, without parsing the PayPal emails? I am using Python for this integration.
Here's what I have tried so far:

I used the "List transactions" API, but it is not real-time. There is apparently a 3-hour delay in production and a 6-hour delay in sandbox mode.
I tried using webhooks, but only the PAYMENT.CAPTURE.COMPLETED webhook is triggered for a direct payment. This webhook provides the transaction_id, which I then used to retrieve the "Show captured payment details". However, the details are empty except for the amount and fees, with no information about the customer. (This observation is based on testing in sandbox mode. I'm not sure if there is a difference in the data sent in production.)

The reason I need the customer information is to reconcile the payment in my ERP system. With only the paid amount, it's not possible to do a reliable matching.
Through my research, I found references to the IPN (Instant Payment Notification), but it seems to be deprecated now. I'm unsure what other options I can explore from my side.
Can anyone provide guidance on how to retrieve real-time customer information for PayPal payments using the API or webhooks in Python? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

How are customers making the PayPal payment? This influences what information will be part of the transaction, for example whether there will be a shipping address or not.

All we give them is the Email address they should send the money to. So they log into their paypal account and send the money to that address.
We dont send them a link or anything.

Currently the best solution will be to create your own simple payment page with a standard integration, and not use webhooks (the immediate capture API response will be sufficient)
If the "Pay link or button" at https://www.paypal.com/buttons supported webhooks, that type of link would be an alternate solution -- but it only supports IPN. IPN is very old and extremely clunky, while it is technically possible to integrate it should be considered effectively deprecated, I do not recommend doing anything new with it.

what about the paypal.me links?
I was thinking about sending a paypal.me link to the customer instead of our paypal email. but I can not find any info on what the webhook would return in the case the customer would pay via this link.
and when i try to create this link in the sandbox mode I get an error, that it can not be created. I could also not find any info if you can get the paypal.me to run in sandbox.

Not tested but as far as I know it's the same as the Pay link or button, not supported by webhooks

thanks for your input. I ended up using the transaction search again. it has all info I need and I tested how long it takes between the arrival of the payment email from paypal and the payment showing up in the transaction search and so far i am at around 30 minutes time difference (for a cron that runs every 15 minutes). that is enough for my use case.
they should really add in their documentation, that the time it takes for payments to show up in the transaction_search is way different on the sandbox and the live system...would have saved me a ton of time..
